# Wordpress get_query_var() not working

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have been trying to get `add_query_arg()` and `get_query_var()` to work in my custom Wordpress theme for hours with no success.
I have searched and tried various 'resolutions' to no avail, and cannot work out what I am missing, any help would be appreciated.
I am trying to create a custom edit post page and looking to pass a URL query var of `?pid=` variable to pass in the post ID.
I currently have:

## functions.php

```
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
    $vars[] = "pid";
    return $vars;
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );
```

## content-single.php

```
<a href="<?php echo add_query_arg( array('pid' => get_the_ID()), get_site_url() . '/new-post' ) ?>">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i> Edit Post
</a>
```

## page-new-post.php

```
<div>
    <?php echo 'pid: ' . get_query_var('pid', 'Not Set'); ?>
</div>
```

The result is always `Not Set`.
I have tried other variable names to ensure avoiding any Wordpress default vars, but none work.

Is there anything else I need to add to enable custom vars, or am I making a silly typo or anything?

Comment: I had some weird problem with `pid` try use some other name like `test` and check if its work for you

Comment: @Shibi, thanks but unfortunately no good. I have just tried `test` and same thing.

Comment: Not WordPress standards but you could just use $_GET to read the variables from the url. Be sure to check whether `isset( $_GET['pid'] ) `.

Comment: @BasvanDijk, I did think this, and is does seem to work but only on a second variable. i.e. `new-post/?test=118` and `$_GET['test']` produces a blank, but if I put an artificial query var `new-post/?artificial=t&test=118` and look for `$_GET['test']` I get 118, which is great and what I want, but `$_GET['artificial']` (`artificial` could be anything) reveals nothing. So this will work if I always pass an artificial variable in.

Answer (score 1):

This post is a little old, but here is a solution.

So, I had the same problem and it was an error in my nginx configuration file. The solution is to pass the `$query_string` variable in my nginx like :

```
location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

If you have an Apache configuration, try searching for a similar solution.